# React: как скопировать все className из jsx в scss?

Tags: css, reactjs, классы, scss

Подскажите пожалуйста, как скопировать все className из jsx в scss?

ps. eCSStractor не срабатывает даже если настроить его на className

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пока что начал использовать BEM Helper - он генерит новый файл с вложенной структурой - что по сути и нужно...фоном продолжу искать дополнение которое просто позволяет скопировать и потом вставить имена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный и самый безболезненный способ решения данной проблемы, это поправить экстеншн своими ручками, опираясь на pull request пользователя, который уже решил данную проблему прямо на странице плагина, но разрабы не запушили это в мастер.

[Ссылка на pull request](https://github.com/yurasovm/eCSStractor-for-VSCode/pull/3). Сами плагины VS Code хранятся по дефолту в папке: %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions

После переноса кода у меня всё заработало.